# Preimage of $x^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=x^2$ and let $B=[-1,1]$. My book then says that the preimage $f^{-1} (B)=[-1,1]$
But this seems unresonable to me. $f$ does does not map the domain to negative values, i.e. $ f: A  \rightarrow B$ always means that $B\geq 0$. Is there an explanation for this perhaps? Thank you.

Comment: You are looking for all $x$ such that $-1 \leq x^2 \leq 1$. This is true for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: @Gregor Yes but $x^2 \geq 0$

Comment: @Ioannis But still $x^2\geq 0\geq -1$.

Comment: your question does not seem to be reasonable.. what is your $A$ and what is your $B$... do you mean  $A=B=[-1,1]$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I have already noted what $B$ is, and $A$ is an arbitrary set I use to make the point that the range of the function, no matter what $A$, cannot be negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that while the *notation* for preimages looks like an inverse function, the analogy is somewhat loose. In particular it **is not expected** that $f(f^{-1}(B))$ will necessarily equal $B$.

By definition $f^{-1}(B)$ is the set of all $x$ such that $x^2\in B$. This set is exactly $[-1,1]$, because the squares of all numbers between $-1$ and $1$ happen to be between $-1$ and $1$ and the squares of a number *outside* this interval is always larger than $1$ and therefore not in $B$.

In particular, for example, $-\frac 12$ needs to be in $f^{-1}(B)$ becasue $(-\frac 12)^2 = \frac 14 \in B$.

$[-1,1]$ is also the preimage of some *other* sets, such as $[0,1]$ or $(-2,1]$ or $[-23\pi+\log 3, 1]$ or $(-\infty,1]$. That is not problematic.

Comment: +1. And, as Henning is well aware, the set $f(f^{-1}(B))$ is exactly known, this is $B\cap\mathrm{Im}(f)$.

Answer (score 2):

Even though $x^2$ does not map to $[-1,0)$, the pre-image of $x^2$ to $[-1,1]$ must include all $x$ that map to anywhere in the interval. Since $(-1)^2 = 1$, it is necessary to include $-1$ in the pre-image.

In other words, $B$ is "larger" than it needs to be, The answer would be the same for $B=[0,1]$.

Comment: Ah ok. So we define $B$ rather loosely. Thanks.